# Merge two User Accounts

Tags: support, status-completed, user-accounts, duplicate-accounts

I have accidently created two user accounts but logging in with two different OpenID's, I foogot I already had an account.  Is there a way to merge the two accounts into one as I have questions on one account and some kudos on the other.

The two accounts are https://askubuntu.com/users/3038/stephen-judge and https://askubuntu.com/users/5716/stephen-judge

Comment: Not sure if this will work, but from your user page you can add an "alternative openID" - how about trying to add the 'other' openID on one of your accounts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your accounts have been merged.

Comment: i had two accounts to.please can you merge them for me? they are smit17av@gmail.com and smit17.2000@gmail.com. i am not using this account anymore as i use smit17av@gmail.com you can also delete this one too.