# Merge my accounts

Tags: support, user-accounts

Sorry guys, but I completly forgot that I already had created this account (using facebook) and I created a new one (using lauchpad), if there is some way to merge the accounts I would enjoy it, but if it's not possible, please delete this user.

Comment: @ElderGeek In spite of the title, this was sort of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/185080). The actual goal of this question was to *merge* the accounts--deletion was only requested in the event that this could not be done. [The answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1601/22949) (posted by a moderator and accepted by the OP) indicates the merge was completed. So I don't think this should be closed as a duplicate of the new general account-deletion question, which does not mention merging.

Comment: @EliahKagan Agreed and edited title accordingly to make that more clear. Deleted comment but sadly cannot retract my close vote.

Comment: @ElderGeek Thanks for the edit! I don't think it's really a problem *here* if you can't retract your close vote--this probably wont be closed now and if it is it can be reopened. But in general the SE system allows users to retract close votes, and I assume that applies on meta. So if it doesn't let you, that seems like a bug.

Comment: @EliahKagan      I don't know whether that refers to meta or not and haven't researched that as yet so I hesitate to open a bug report until I know. Be that as it may, I believe I've made a good case for merging this question and https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/679/merge-two-user-accounts?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Done and done :)

You can log in to your account with both open-ids now. If you want to change this, see your profile settings (the "alt openid" section).

And just comment on this answer if you need anything else